# Transitioning from pandas .apply to a vectoriztion approach

Tags: python, pandas, vectorization

I am trying to improve a pandas iteration with a purely vectorization approach. I am a little new to vectoriztion and am having trouble getting it to work.

Within one dataframe field, I am finding all the unique string-based records of addresses. I need to seach the dataframe for each unique address idividually and assign a single unique identifier to the returned records. In this way, I can have 1 UID for each each address regardless of multiple occurances in the dataframe.

I have developed an approach that utilizes vectorition with the pandas .apply method.

```
def addr_id(x):
    global df
    df['Unq_ID'][df['address'] == x] = uuid.uuid4()

pd.DataFrame(df['address'].unique(), columns=["column1"]).apply(lambda x: addr_id(x["column1"]), axis=1)
```

However, I am trying to do away with the .apply method completely. This is where I am stuck.

```
df['Unq_ID'][df['address'] == (pd.DataFrame(df['address'].unique(), columns=["column1"]))["column1"]] = uuid.uuid4()
```

I keep getting a **ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to get rid of the Pandas apply due to performance reasons, right?

May I suggest a different approach to your problem?

You can construct a dict with the unique values of column1 as keys and the uuids as values and then map them to the DataFrame:

```
uuid_dict = {key: uuid.uuid4() for key in df['column1'].unique()}
df['address'] = df.column1.map(uuid_dict)
```

This would be very fast because it avoids looping in Python (which Pandas apply does under the hood).

Comment: Oh that is a fantastic idea. I think thats going to work exactly like I need it to! Thanks lungben